# How can I horizontally center a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I make `UIView` horizontally centered and 30px from the top of the view controller using `CGRectMake`?

```
var draggableView: DraggableView = DraggableView(frame:CGRectMake(0 , 30, 260, 260))
draggableView.center = center
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try:

```
let size = 260
let screenWidth = self.view.frame.size.width

let frame = CGRectMake((screenWidth / 2) - (size / 2), 30, size, size)
let draggableView = DraggableView(frame: frame)

self.view.addSubview(draggableView)
```

Answer (score 41):

Swift 3;

```
subView.center.x = view.center.x
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Simple and clean.

Comment: nice solution, its so simple

Answer (score 12):

You cannot center a view in a view controller, because a view controller is not a view and doesn't have a coordinate system.

You can center a view relative to another view.  Presumably you want to center `draggableView` relative to the view controller's view.  Assuming `self` is the view controller, and `draggableView` will be a direct subview of the view controller's view:

```
var draggableView: DraggableView = DraggableView(frame:CGRectMake(0 , 30, 260, 260))
self.view.addSubview(draggableView)
draggableView.center = self.view.center
```

Answer (score 3):

Although Rob Mayoff is correct, it might be worthwhile to consider centering your frame in *viewWillLayoutSubviews*, which is called upon device rotation. You can also use the properties **center.x** and **center.y** of center to align based on axis. No need to call self in this instance.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    draggableView.center = view.center
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using the '*MMMaterialDesignSpinner*' library and creating a custom activity indicator in center of view. It's working correctly, you can change your custom view name like 'DraggableView'. I hope it's usable by you. This code is added into the `viewDidLoad` function in swift 3.

```
var loader = MMMaterialDesignSpinner()
let size:CGFloat = 40.0
let screenWidth = self.view.frame.size.width
let screenHeight = self.view.frame.size.height

loader = MMMaterialDesignSpinner(frame: CGRect(x: (screenWidth / 2) - (size / 2), y: (screenHeight / 2) - (size / 2), width: size, height: size))

loader.tintColor = UIColor.blue
loader.lineWidth = 4.0
loader.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;
view.addSubview(loader)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5

```
// in viewDidLoad or viewWillLayoutSubviews
draggableView.frame.origin.x = view.bounds.midX - draggableView.bounds.midX
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a neat little extension for centering a view or object:

```
extension CGPoint {
    static var Center: CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxX/2, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY/2)
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
textField.center = CGPoint.Center
```

Answer (score 0):

activityindicater is the view which you want to put in the center

**self.activityindicater.center = self.baseView.center**